# How do I add a criteria to a query on one table but keep all the records from another?

Tags: ms-access

I have the following query:

```
SELECT games_atp.ID1_G, odds_atp.K1
FROM games_atp LEFT JOIN odds_atp ON (games_atp.ID1_G = odds_atp.ID1_O) AND (games_atp.ID2_G = odds_atp.ID2_O) AND (games_atp.ID_T_G = odds_atp.ID_T_O) AND (games_atp.ID_R_G = odds_atp.ID_R_O)
```

I know the joining is convoluted but the original db is built without a primary key. The above works fine and importantly pulls all the records from `games_atp`. I now want to add a criteria into this to pull only certain `K1` records from `odds_atp`. I added a `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT games_atp.ID1_G, odds_atp.K1
FROM games_atp LEFT JOIN odds_atp ON (games_atp.ID1_G = odds_atp.ID1_O) AND (games_atp.ID2_G = odds_atp.ID2_O) AND (games_atp.ID_T_G = odds_atp.ID_T_O) AND (games_atp.ID_R_G = odds_atp.ID_R_O)
WHERE (((odds_atp.ID_B_O)=2));
```

However, this overides the left join and only pulls records from `games_atp` where there is a corresponding record in `odds_atp` with `ID_B_O` = 2. How do I keep the criteria and all the records in `games_atp`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current where condition will filter your final result, hence you are only seeing `id_B_O = 2`.

However, you could also add the wehre condition directly into your left join.

something like this.

```
SELECT 
    games_atp.ID1_G, odds_atp.K1
FROM
    games_atp
        LEFT JOIN odds_atp ON 
        (
            (odds_atp.ID_B_O =2)
            AND
            (
                (games_atp.ID1_G      = odds_atp.ID1_O)
                AND (games_atp.ID2_G  = odds_atp.ID2_O)
                AND (games_atp.ID_T_G = odds_atp.ID_T_O)
                AND (games_atp.ID_R_G = odds_atp.ID_R_O)
            )
        );
```

or you could also take advantage of `sub-queries`

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd slightly simplified the query for this post but I can't get the full version to work:

Comment: `SELECT games_atp.ID1_G, odds_atp.K1
FROM players_atp INNER JOIN (stat_atp RIGHT JOIN (tours_atp RIGHT JOIN (games_atp LEFT JOIN odds_atp ON (odds_atp.ID_B_O = 2) AND ((games_atp.ID_R_G = odds_atp.ID_R_O) AND (games_atp.ID_T_G = odds_atp.ID_T_O) AND (games_atp.ID2_G = odds_atp.ID2_O) AND (games_atp.ID1_G = odds_atp.ID1_O))) ON tours_atp.ID_T = games_atp.ID_T_G) ON (stat_atp.ID1 = games_atp.ID1_G) AND (stat_atp.ID2 = games_atp.ID2_G) AND (stat_atp.ID_T = games_atp.ID_T_G) AND (stat_atp.ID_R = games_atp.ID_R_G)) ON players_atp.ID_P = games_atp.ID1_G`

Comment: I also get an error trying to view your sql in design view - 'can't represent the join'. It does run but when I save and go back into it then all of the joins have been removed and I'm only left with a from clause with the two tables `games_atp` and `odds_atp`